# Is this grading of $B_f$ correct?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

This picture is from Qing Liu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves.
In Lemma 3.36, $B$ is a graded ring. Is the grading of $B_f$ defined between line 10 and line 12 in page 52 correct? Let $f\in B_+$ be a homogeneous element of degree r, then $r>0$, how to express $\frac{1}{f}$ as a sum of finite homogeneous elements in $B_f$?

Comment: what makes you think that the grading is i ``incorrect"?

Comment: If there is any justice, the degree of $bf^{-N} = \frac{b}{f^N}$ should be $\deg(b) - \deg(f^N) = \deg(b) - N\deg(f) = \deg(b) - Nr$, as $f$ is assumed to be of degree $r$. Thus the elements of degree $n$ in $B_f$ should reasonably be the $\frac{b}{f^N}$ such that $\deg(b) - Nr = n$ (in other words, $\deg(b) = Nr + n$).

Comment: Can the degree $n$ of homogeneous elements in this grading of $B_f$ be less than $0$? Is the degree of $\frac{1}{f}$ equal to $-r$?